# Placing .emacs config file under version repo

Tags: emacs

Where does emacs look for the .emacs file? Is it simply looking for the file that is accessible anywhere in the PATH? Right now I simply have it in my user home directory on OS X. I have read that it is wise to place this file under version repo, which would mean moving it to a new directory and putting a .git in there (my VCS preference). Is this fine? How does emacs know where the file is located?

Comment: If you want to get really fancy, you can also create a `site-start.el` within the `.../lisp` directory of the source (e.g., within the packaged *.app) and use the answer of `Sibi` to place that one-liner within `site-start.el`.  This contemplates a generic installation of Emacs built `--with-ns` -- something like Aquamacs is more difficult to configure and requires advanced steps during the build process to take total control over file / directory locations.  I have my entire Emacs installation in `~/.0.data/.0.emacs` and I've also configured Emacs for XP in Parallels to use that directory.

Comment: As an alternative you can take a look at VCSH,https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh. This will keep more of your files in your home directory under version control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Emacs 23, the variable `user-emacs-directory` holds the location of `.emacs.d`

You can get a more detailed explanation [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsDotD)

Putting your configuration file under a git repository is good. Just use .gitignore to the files you don't want to track!

My suggestion is to put your custom configuration Emacs lisp file under some directory and then load them in your [Init file](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile) (`~/.emacs.d/init.el`) like this:

```
(load "~/myconfig/my_emacs_config.el")
```

Comment: Thanks I will accept this answer if you can inform me where to set this variable within emacs. I presume it is not set in the config file itself, since it tells emacs where to find the config file.

Comment: Ok, so I would have a generic `.emacs` file in the usual place where emacs can find it, and then it merely contains this `load` line to where I have another config file, my "real" config file with my lisp configurations, this file ends in `.el`, is that the idea?

Comment: @OpenLearner Yes, that way you can keep your configuration separately. :)

Comment: What is the point of ~/myconfig/?  Why would you not put your custom elisp in ~/.emacs.d/?

Comment: @jpkotta It becomes a pain to add lot of ignore rules in `.gitignore`

Answer (score 11):

The simplest thing to do is move your `~/.emacs` file to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. Emacs will find `~/.emacs.d/init.el` automatically.

Then you can put all of `.emacs.d/` under version control.

For example:

```
cd ~
mkdir .emacs.d
mv .emacs .emacs.d/init.el
cd .emacs.d
git init
```